# Error modifying one element in a Python list

Tags: python, list, in-place

I am trying to change an element in a Python list. Following the tutorial on https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/matrix, I came up with the code below.

```
 matrix = [[0]*6]*3
 print(matrix)
 matrix[0][0] = 2
 print(matrix)
```

Upon running the code, I received the following output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Notice the last line of output, how the first element of every sub-list is set to `2`. How do I make it so that only the first element of the first list is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic python [gotcha](https://gist.github.com/sergray/6063222) to do with the fact that all python objects are *references*. In your case this means that `matrix[0] is matrix[1] is matrix[2]` since `is` is `True` if two objects are the same thing in memory.

Do this instead

```
matrix = [[0]*6 for _ in range(3)]
```

Now `matrix[0] is matrix[1] is matrix[2]` returns `False`.

Alternatively, use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) which was made for manipulating numerical arrays without these issues.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation as well sir. Have a great day :D

Answer (score 0):

This is because each row in your matrix isn't an individual array, but a reference to the same array.

The following will print out the memory location for each row:

```
for row in matrix:
    print(id(row))
```

Notice that they are all the same. This is because lists in python are passed by-reference, not copying each individual value.

What you are essentially doing in part two of your code is:

```
row = [0] * 6
matrix = [row, row, row]
```

You might be better off with something like this:

```
matrix = [[0 for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(3)]
matrix[0][0] = 2
[[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Which creates a new array full of `0` for each row you are creating in the matrix.